# Linq Generic OrderBy selector

Tags: entity-framework-4, pagination, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the repository pattern in a asp.net mvc application (v3) and EntityFramework (v4).
I would like to add to the repository paging functionality. I have the following sample code:

```
public PagedResult<T> GetPaged(int offset = 0, int limit = PagedResult<T>.NoLimit, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null) 
    {      
      var res = BaseQ.Where(_predicate);//.Skip(offset);
      if (predicate != null)
        res = res.Where(predicate);

      res = res.Skip(offset);

      if (limit != PagedResult<T>.NoLimit)
      {
        res = res.Take(limit);
      }

      return new PagedResult<T>(res, res.Count(), offset, limit);
    }
```

However, this will not work because Entity framework throws an exception that I should call `OrderBy` before `Skip`.
I am wondering how can I implement this in a generic way so that the order by expression will be plugged in from the outside. I would then pass it as a parameter.
Perhaps there is also another way of working around that problem.

**[EDIT]** I found out that this can be done by passing in the name of the property and creating an expression out of that, but I would like to actually just use it as I am using it in the OrderBy. So just pass in `(c=>c.ID)` for example.

Thanks in advance for any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to go with passing in a string and creating the expression from it